# limit as x tends to 0 of $(x+(5/6)x^3+(41/120)x^5-x)/x^3$

Tags: limits

I have this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+\frac{5}{6}x^3 + \frac{41}{120}x^5 - x}{x^3}$$

I do not understand why it equals $\frac{5}{6}$. If you divide by the cubic u get a high power x squared which should tend to infinity?

Can someone explain why it is $\frac{5}{6}$?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: yes but I wanted to give full question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+\frac{5}{6}x^3+\frac{41}{120}x^5-x}{x^3}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{5}{6}x^3+\frac{41}{120}x^5}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{41}{120}x^2\right)\\
&=\frac{5}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ye thanks, I think I just had a black out, so simple